# why my code 'next()' function not called in this example?

Tags: python, iterator

```
class a(object):
    w={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.w)
    def next(self):#this is not be called
        print 'sss'
        for i in self.w:
            return i

b=a()
for i in b:
    print i
```

and what is Relations between `__iter__` and `next`  function.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but the `next()` function isn't called because you never explicitly call it. You define `__iter__`, which gets called when you do:

```
for i in b:
```

This should implicitly call the .next() method of the iterator, but the iterator isn't `a`, but rather `iter(self.w)`. As your object is not the iterator, its `next()` method is never called.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In `__iter__()` you return an iterator on the dict stored in `self.w`, not on the class itself. Returning `self` instead will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

`next` should remember the last position and return the next item (not always return the first item, like in your code), and when there are no further items, raise the `StopIteration` exception.

Also `__iter__` should return the class itself.

See [Python documentation for iterators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

In your case, using [generator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types) is more suitable:

```
class a(object):
    w={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
    def __iter__(self):
        print 'sss'
        for i in self.w:
            yield i

b=a()
for i in b:
    print i
```